# Displaying tabular type data in .net winforms

Tags: .net, winforms

I want to display tabular type data, but it will not be coming from a single datasource.  I am currently using a label, but the alignment doesn't look that great.

Any ideas?

Again, the data is not being loaded from a datagrid or anything, each row is basically a label and a number e.g.

Total Users: 10123
Total Logins: 234

What is the best way to display this, any built-in control I should be using?

Comment: do you want this to be displayed dynamically?

Comment: and is WPF an option? or winforms only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options:

1. organize your data into a
   datatable and use a grid control.
2. use the [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) to align
   you information.

Comment: +1 on TableLayoutPanel. Dock.Fill the labels and set TextAlign to MiddleLeft

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a datagrid to display data I sugest using a textbox with a monospace font at least, like courier new.